# Wrong MIME type after using sharp API with Firebase/Angular app

Tags: angular, image, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, sharp

I am calling `sharp(tmpFilePath).resize(150, 150).toFile(resizedFilePath)` (using this sharp api: http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/v0.15.1/api/) but the output file that's being produced is showing as type `application/octet-stream` rather than an `image/jpeg`, which is the original file type.  I am using Angular and downloading/uploading to Firebase storage via cloud functions.  When I download the source file and upload it right back to Firebase without calling the sharp API first, the newly uploaded file is an `image/jpeg` file as expected.

I was originally following this tutorial (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/image-thumbnail-resizer-cloud-function/) but I actually couldn't access my storage bucket using his method, OR the one on Firebase docs: `const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();` but I was able to access it through the admin with `const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);`. It seems suspicious that I had to use this work-around, but again, my function works well if I leave out the `sharp` api call...so I just don't know that it's the root cause of my problem?

I submitted this issue on github (https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1493) but the owner seems to think the issue is not related to `sharp`.  Any idea what I've done wrong here?  Or can anyone at least help me to narrow the problem down so I can try some better google searches?

Original file:
[image]

File returned by Sharp API:
[image]

My function from index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { join, dirname } from 'path';

import * as sharp from 'sharp';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const resizeImages = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => { 
try {
    console.log(object);
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName:string = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);
    console.log("filePath: " + filePath + "; fileName: " + fileName + "; bucketDir: " + bucketDir);

    if (bucketDir === 'profile-image' && object.contentType.includes('image')){
        console.log("A profile picture was added...")
        //The file is a profile picture...
        if (fileName.includes('unsized@')) {
            console.log("The picture that was added hasn't been sized yet...")
            //The file needs to be resized...
                const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
                const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, fileName);

                // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
                await fs.ensureDir(workingDir); 

                // 2. Download Source File
                await bucket.file(filePath).download({
                destination: tmpFilePath
                });
                console.log("Downloaded the source file");
                console.log(tmpFilePath);

                // 3. Resize the image  ********THIS PART IS NOT HAPPENING CORRECTLY
                console.log("About to start resizing...");
                const resizedfileName: string = fileName.split('@').pop();
                const resizedFilePath = join(workingDir, resizedfileName);
                await sharp(tmpFilePath).resize(150, 150).toFile(resizedFilePath);
                console.log("The image resizing is complete: "+ resizedFilePath);

                // 4. Upload the resized image
                const resizedImageUploadSnapshot = await bucket.upload(resizedFilePath, {destination: join('profile-image', resizedfileName)});
                console.log("Uploaded the resized image ");

                // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
                await fs.remove(workingDir);
                console.log("FUNCTION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!")
                return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {     
        console.log('exiting function');
        return false;
    }

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
}
```

My package.json file from the functions folder:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.21.0",
    "stripe": "^6.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a file extension to my paths, as follows:

```
const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, fileName + '.jpeg');
```

and

```
const resizedFilePath = join(workingDir, resizedfileName + '.jpeg');
```